# Convergence in Distribution for a 2D Random Vector

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose that $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ are independent Uniform$[0, 1]$ random variables. Let $$Y_n = n(1-\text{max}(X_1, X_2, ..., X_n)), Z_n = n\text{min}(X_1, X_2, ..., X_n).$$
I wish to prove that the vector $(Y_n, Z_n)$ converges in distribution to some distribution $(Y, Z)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, and to prove that such $Y$
and $Z$ are independent.

To prove the first, let $(t_1, t_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2.$ Then,
\begin{align}
P(Y_n \leq t_1, Z_n \leq t_2) &= P(n(1-\text{max}(X_1, X_2, ..., X_n))\leq t_1, n\text{min}(X_1, X_2, ..., X_n) \leq t_2) \\ &= P\left(\text{max}(X_1, X_2, ..., X_n) \geq 1 -\frac{t_1}{n}, \text{min}(X_1, X_2, ..., X_n) \leq \frac{t_2}{n}\right).
\end{align}
I am confused how the simplification should proceed. Evidently, it would be simpler if the expression were instead of the form
\begin{align}
P\left(\text{max}(X_1, X_2, ..., X_n) \leq 1 -\frac{t_1}{n}, \text{min}(X_1, X_2, ..., X_n) \geq \frac{t_2}{n}\right).
\end{align}

Comment: Then why not consider $P(Y_n \geq t_1, Z_n \geq t_2)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write
$$
\mathbb P(Y_n\leqslant t_1,Z_n\leqslant t_2)=1-\mathbb P(\{Y_n>t_1\}\cup \{Z_n>t_2\})=1-\mathbb P(Y_n> t_1)-\mathbb P(Z_n> t_2)+
\mathbb P(Y_n> t_1,Z_n> t_2).
$$